# c# SerialPort PinChanged event handling

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a null terminated serial port listener and I want it to pass on all data and pin events from the in port to the out port. The data is working well however I want to pass on all the pin events as well. I've added a listener using:

```
in_port.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(port_PinChanged);
```

and then handle it with:

```
    static void port_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.Break)
        {
            out_port.BreakState = in_port.BreakState;
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.CDChanged)
        {
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.CtsChanged)
        {
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.DsrChanged)
        {
        }
        else if (e.EventType == SerialPinChange.Ring)
        {

        }
    }
```

How can I pass these changes in pin state to the out port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't going to work.  CD and Ring are modem signals, they are wired as inputs on your PC.  You don't have spare outputs that you could use to drive these signals.  CTS and DSR are handshake signals that are wired to RTS and DTR on the other end.  You need to use them yourself to implement handshaking, on both ports.  Break cannot work well either, you don't know when it turns off, although you could simulate it with a timer.  Don't bother, that signal dates from the stone age.

RS-232 just isn't made for this.  Instead wire it directly and tap the signals.  TxD+Gnd to one port, RxD+Gnd to another so you can snoop on the traffic.  Not the greatest for noise, keep the cables short or baudrate low.  Soldering iron required.

Answer (score 1):

The CtsChanged and DsrChanged pin states are reactions to other things happening, you should not try to pass them on in this way. They relate to the dataflow.

I'm not sure about the other signals.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason I was looking at this was there is an application at one end communicating with a device over the port. Some of the device commands are failing (not the writes) so my first thought was to pass on when a pin changes. Is there a better way to do this?